# Reference column from next row with different value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset with this form:

```
df <- data.frame(event = c("request","request","response", "request"), 
      value = 1:4)
event      value
request     1
request     2
response    3
request     4
```

I'd like  write to `next_different_event_value`, the `value` in the row with next *different*  `event`. Desired output:

```
event      value    next_different_event_value
request     1       3
request     2       3
response    3       4
request     4       NA
```

Ideally, I can do this with tidyverse approach and without joins.

Thanks.

Comment: For more context, my actual `value`  column is timestamp data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>%
 mutate(next_different_event_value = ifelse(event != lead(event), lead(value), NA)) %>%
 fill(next_different_event_value, .direction = "up")

     event value next_different_event_value
1  request     1                          3
2  request     2                          3
3 response     3                          4
4  request     4                         NA
```

It compares whether the "event" is the same as the next "event" row. If not, it assigns the value from the next "event" row, otherwise it assigns NA. Then, it fills the missing values with the last non-NA value from down to up.

Comment: this solved the underlying problem for me: https://github.com/robinsones/funneljoin